# How can I access individual shape geometry after geometry merge in three.js?

Tags: three.js

Say I have 100 different shape geometries, which I have merged using:

```
THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(geometry1, geometry2)
```

Will I still be able to update the geometry of individual shapes and not all of them? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could a) take note of the vertex offset of each geometry (i.e. how many vertices are already in the merged geometry before merging the latest one) and then use that to only loop through and modify a certain geometry or b) if each one has a distinguished material, you can loop through all the faces and restrict your modifications to those vertices that are attached to a face with a correct material.

However, as it's still a one big geometry, you would be pushing the whole thing to the GPU regardless of how little you edited it. If you are only modifying it occasionally, it may not matter, but in that case you should check if you can get enough performance from just re-merging the whole thing and not bother with anything more complex.

If you really need to push only the modified data to the GPU, there exists a `void bufferSubData(GLenum target, GLintptr offset, ArrayBufferView data)` function for that. However, that is raw WebGL and you would need to dive into three.js' internals in order to patch that in.